# Why doesn't vim ask for password when reopenning an encrypted file?

Tags: vim

If I run Vim and then open an encrypted file it asks for the encryption password. If I close the window where the file was opened (without closing vim) and then reopen the file, the password prompt is not shown anymore. Is there any setting to modify this behavior? I'd like vim to ask the password every time the file is opened regardless if it's the same Vim "session".

Comment: Are you sure you are reopening the file (`:e`) instead of just hiding and unhiding a buffer?

Comment: @jw013 Good point. It really puzzled me, how the behavior can be possible since the swap file is also encrypted.

Comment: Are you using `gvim` or some other GUI variant? If so which one and on what platform?

Comment: @Caleb I'm using gvim on Ubuntu 11.04 (package vim-gnome)

Comment: @jw013 I'm closing the window with `:q` then open a new tab with `:t`. If I use `:e` the same happens. How can I know if I'm hiding a buffer?

Comment: @ivotron: `:q` only closes a window - if you have `'hidden'`set the buffer simply becomes hidden - the file is not actually closed.  Use `:ls` or `:buffers` to list all buffers.

Comment: @jw013 Maybe you could post this as an answer - people might find it useful.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz Done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the vim documentation, `:q` closes the current window and only quits if there are no windows left.  In vim, windows are merely "viewports" where buffers can be displayed.  The vim documentation itself sums this up quite nicely.  From `:help window`:

```
A buffer is the in-memory text of a file.
A window is a viewport on a buffer.
A tab page is a collection of windows.
```

If you have the `hidden` option set, closing a window hides the buffer but does not "`abandon`" it, so vim is still keeping track of the contents.  With `'hidden'` set, when you "reopen" the file, you are simply re-showing/un-hiding the buffer, not actually re-opening the file on disk.

For more information take a look at

```
:help hidden
:help abandon
```